# How to convert date from dd/MM to dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have to change the format of the date from dd/MM to dd/MM/yyyy and I use this code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "28/07")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date ?? Date())
```

The output is: 28/07/2000. What is wrong?

Comment: How is this possible? You have not provided a year then how swift know to take which year?

Comment: What should be the expected outcome?

Comment: @RajaKishan i'm new to swift, and this is provided by API

Comment: @koen it should be 28/07/2021

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add current year, use this:

```
let date = Date()
let calender = Calendar.current
let components = calender.dateComponents([.year], from: date)

let year = components.year
```

and add this 'year' after your date string. Then you will have a date and current year.